# Получить список администраторов группы, в которой есть бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telepot

Есть группа, в которую добавлен бот. Надо узнать, является ли бот администратором этой группы.
Используется библиотека `telepot`, `python 3.5.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберток над нативным API великое множество, найти конкретный пример на конкретную либу это поиск готового ответа. Я решал 1-1 задачу на другой либе и могу описать алгоритм, так как методы везде одноименные проблем не должно возникнуть.

1. Получаем чат `getChat(chat_id)` , если метод вернул результат значит чат есть
2. Получаем администраторов канала `getChatAdministrators(chat_id)`
3. Получаем свой id для поиска его в списке администраторов `getMe()`
4. Бежим по списку администраторов ища среди них себя
5. Если среди администраторов бот есть, определяем уровень доступа к каналу, обычно что бы разделять и властвовать в канале нужно что бы объект `ChatMember` имел следующие привилегии:

> 'status' : 'administrator'
>
> 'can_post_messages' : true
>
> 'can_edit_messages' : true
>
> 'can_delete_messages' : true

Если условия совпали, то ,бот админ и можете постить, удалять, изменять сообщения.
если нужны большие привилегии то проверяем их. Все флаги объекта `ChatMember` описаны тут : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember