# Выведение админов группы

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Хочу разобраться, как работает bot.get_chat_administrators и как его правильно использовать? Если быть кратко, нужно, что бы бот выводил юзернейм, имя и фамилию админа. Желательно на примере показать

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте вопрос **StackOverflow** [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766601/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82), там  всё описано.

Также копирую кусочек статьи с [официального сайта](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators):

> **getChatAdministrators**.
> Используйте этот метод, чтобы получить список администраторов в чате. В случае успеха возвращает массив объектов **ChatMember**, который содержит информацию обо всех администраторах чата, кроме других ботов. Если чат является группой или супергруппой и администраторы не были назначены, будет возвращен только создатель.

Помог?

Comment: На примере показать можно?

Comment: Ну `getChatAdministrators(chat_id)` впишите и всё. Вместо `chat_id` естественно ваш ID чата